# Насколько плохо с точки зрения СЕО спрятать h1 под картинку, если на картинке есть текст, и он соответствует или почти соответствует h1?

Tags: seo

Имеется простой сайт, на котором всего одна страница. Логотип и h1 - это одно целое. В дизайне текст в логотипе закруглен. То есть, идет не по горизонтали, а дугой. Написать это с помощью CSS и HTML нельзя (так, чтобы это был 1 элемент, а не по одной буковке выводить (по одной буковке плохо для СЕО)).
Я хочу вставить картинку с закругленным текстом. И под нее разместить h1 с таким же текстом (или + небольшое описание). Насколько плохо так делать с точки зрения СЕО? Я читал, что любые попытки спрятать h1 рассматриваются, как попытки обмануть поискового робота и ведут к бану сайта или потере эффективности h1. 
Хочу узнать, так ли это в моем случае.

Comment: А есть ли установленные правила для SEO, спецификации? Или эту отрасль создали из воздуха :)

Comment: @Visman Документация от Гугл: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35291 ++ http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.ru/ru/ru/intl/ru/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide-ru.pdf и документация от Moz https://moz.com/learn/seo ++ SerachEngineLand https://searchengineland.com/library/channel/seo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, если спрятанное содержание дублирует видимое содержание, то это не нарушение. Но никто не знает поисковых алгоритмов Гугл и они меняются почти 2 раза каждый день. Поэтому лучшее решение - это избегать подобного. Не понятно, почему вы отвергаете создание лого с CSS. Пример лого с использованием стилей:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<style>body{background:#dcdcdc;font-family:Verdana}ul{list-style-type:none}li{margin:0}#main{background:#dcdcdc;min-height:40vw;width:100vw;margin:56px auto 0;max-width:960px;box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)}a{text-decoration:none}
header{margin:0;width:100%;text-align:center;font-size:1.3em;border-bottom:2px solid #ddd;box-shadow:0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);transition:all 200ms ease-out;background:#bababa;text-shadow:#e0e0e0 1px 1px 0;padding-top:.5em;padding-bottom:.5em;font-family:Courier;font-weight:bold}header a{color:#696969}header a:hover{color:#dcdcdc;text-shadow:none}header:hover{background:#2f4f4f;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<a href=../../index.html target=_self><strong>eSweden</strong></a>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У вас же в примере горизонтально текст расположен.

Comment: Ну, я думал, что вы самостоятельно можете найти решение в поиске. Смотрите это: https://codepen.io/peterhry/pen/Aayut ++ или же используйте генератор текста http://csswarp.eleqtriq.com/

Comment: А разве такое решение подходит для h1? Там же очень много span'ов по одной буковке. Поисковой робот сможет соединить их в единое целое? И будет ли это равносильно обычному h1, где внутри текст, как единое целое, а не по одной букве?

Comment: Поисковый робот, также как и браузер, читает также стили и скрипты. Поэтому он покажет текст как  браузер. Также можете смотреть этот генератор http://circletype.labwire.ca/

Comment: Элемент span не имеет смыслового значения вообще. Как это видит поисковый бот, вы можете тестировать в Консоле вебмастера Гугл - меню Панель инструментов, слева - выберите Сканирование - выберите опцию Просмотреть как Googlebot.